# When using the batch API, can I setup multiple batch jobs or can I only setup one batch with multiple operations?

Tags: 6, batch-operations

When using the batch API, can I setup multiple batch jobs or can I only setup one batch with multiple operations? I ask because of a data migration I am doing.

Also, will it run the batches and operations in the order they are received or are they run concurrently? I need to have some items imported before others. So I am concerned about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call [batch_set()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/batch_set/6) more than one time, and [batch_process()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/batch_process/6) will execute all the batch sets that have been set with every call to `batch_set()`.

Normally a module will call `batch_set()` once, and pass as `$batch['operations']` an array containing all the functions to call, but if two different modules are setting their own batch sets, they will be both executed.